# CORS error redirecting from Node.js to React after login

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redirect, cors, rtk-query

I am having trouble redirecting from the server side of my Node.js app to the client side React app after a successful login. I have a function that creates a JWT token and redirects the user after login or signup. The function works fine when called directly from the server, but when I make the same request using Axios, cAT, or RTK Query, I get a CORS error during the redirect. I don't want to handle the redirect in the .then() method, but instead, I want to handle it on the server side.

I'm building a web application using Node.js on the server side and React on the client side. The server is running on http://localhost:3001 and the client is running on http://localhost:3000.

I'm facing an issue with CORS when trying to redirect the user to the /app page on the client side after a successful login on the /login page on the server side. Specifically, I'm getting the following error:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/app' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3001/users/login') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
```

I've already tried several solutions from other posts, but none of them worked for me.

Here's what I've done on the server side to enable CORS:

```
app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3000', credentials: true }));
app.options('*', cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3000', credentials: true }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
  next();
});
```

I use the above function to create a JWT token and perform a redirect operation after a successful login, signup, or OAuth request.

```
const createSendToken = (
  user,
  statusCode,
  res,
  remember = false,
  loginType = 'normal'
) => {

  ...

  res.cookie('access', token, cookieOptions);


  if (loginType === 'normal') {
    // res.status(statusCode).json({
    //   status: 'success',
    // });
    res.redirect(`${rootURL}${appURL}`);
  } else if (loginType === 'OAUTH') {
    res.redirect(`${rootURL}${appURL}`);
  }
};
```

This is the code block that contains the login query request, which is created in the authApi.js file.

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

const authApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'auth',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3001',
    credentials: 'include',
  }),
  endpoints(builder) {
    return {
      login: builder.mutation({
        query: credentials => {
          return {
            url: '/users/login',
            method: 'POST',
            body: credentials,
          };
        },
        transformResponse: response => {
          if (response.status === 302) {
            const redirectUrl = new URL(
              response.headers.get('Location'),
              window.location.href
            );
            redirectUrl.searchParams.append('credentials', 'include');
            window.location.href = redirectUrl.href;
            return null;
          }
          return response.json();
        },
      }),

     ......
```

LoginPage.js
I encounter an issue at this point. While making a direct request to the server-side, I am able to successfully redirect to the '/app' path from the server-side.

```
const handleGoogleOAuth = () => {
  window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3001/users/auth/google
};
```

However, when I make a request using Axios, cAT or the RTK Query, I encounter a CORS error during the redirect process, which I am unable to handle. I don't want to navigate in .then(), but rather want the server to handle this for me.

```
const [loginUser, result] = useLoginMutation();

const handleLogin = () =>{
  loginUser(values)
   .unwrap()
   .then(response => console.log(response)
   .catch(err => console.log(err)
   .finally(()=> {})
}
```

There should be a way to perform a server-side redirect as a response to the API request. I would greatly appreciate your assistance in finding a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So I had this problem for days and a spoke to a fellow and he had a solution. I don't have deep knowledge or experience in back-end, just been doing it for a year. Read the article and I am sure it works.

https://www.telerik.com/blogs/dealing-with-cors-in-create-react-app

Lets also look into access-control-origin, I am sure there is a way out